# How to pass multiple queries in url to Django

Tags: django, rest

my urls.py setting is

```
path('somepath', views.somefunc.as_view(), name='SomeFunc')
```

`SomeFunc` takes `POST` and is supposed to take some query commands like

```
localhost:8000/path/to/somepath?a=f&b=g
```

When I print out the request itself, it seems like it's only reading `POST /path/to/somepath?a=f` and I cannot get anything from `request.POST`

How do I read both `a` and `b`?

This is Django2.0 by the way

EDIT:

I feel like I have some misunderstanding of the fundamental of django or even REST in general.

When I try to do a `requests.post` in python as I pass in the queries in the url, somehow those queries show up in `request.GET` on the django side.

My understanding has been that `requests.post` posts the data set in queries  to django, so the queryset should show up in `POST` instead of `GET`

This seems like it's not the case. I wonder what I'm missing here.

using `request.GET` fixes everything..... but it's not really a fix so to speak

Comment: Well yes, you have understood REST - or actually HTTP. A POST contains its data in the body, not in the URL. If for example you did `requests.post('localhost:8000/path/to/somepath', {'a': 'f', 'b': 'g'})`, that dict would be sent as the body in form-encoded format and received in `request.POST`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not POST data, it's GET. You can get it from `request.GET`.

Comment: i'm doing `curl -XPOST localhost:8000/path/to/somepath?a=f&b=g` does it change anything?

Comment: I tried printing out `request.GET` even when i'm using `POST` and I got something, still I'm missing the second query. Seems like now i have two problems to solve

Comment: Looks like using `requests` package can make me get both queries, but somehow it's still a `GET`.....